# ConfigParser VS SafeConfigParser in python 2.7

Tags: python, python-2.7, configparser

What are the differences between `ConfigParser` and `SafeConfigParser`? And why, exactly, is the latter is safer? What's 'unsafe' about `ConfigParser`? I know that `SafeConfigParser` inherited the `ConfigParser`, what did it do different?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The [SafeConfigParser](https://docs.python.org/2/library/configparser.html#safeconfigparser-objects) implements a different `set(section, option, value)` method which will raise a [NoSectionError](https://docs.python.org/2/library/configparser.html#ConfigParser.NoSectionError) if the section does not exists, and a `TypeError` if `value` is not a string.

This allows more control over the behaviour of the parser, an [example](https://docs.python.org/2/library/configparser.html#examples) from documentation:

```
try:
    config.set(section2, option, config.get(section1, option, 1))
except ConfigParser.NoSectionError:
    # Create non-existent section
    config.add_section(section2)
    opt_move(config, section1, section2, option)
else:
    config.remove_option(section1, option)
```

> **From [documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/configparser.html#)**: It also support *interpolation*. This means values can contain format strings which refer to other values in the same section, or values in a special DEFAULT section. Additional defaults can be provided on initialization.

**Update**

I just checked the [source code](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/40a101df8c64a1e55cca2780248d7a92bdcccd57/Lib/ConfigParser.py#L686) of the `SafeConfigParser`, and even if it is true that `ConfigParser` also allows interpolation, `SafeConfigParser` provides an updated version of it that [documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/configparser.html#ConfigParser.SafeConfigParser) describes as *a more-sane and more predictable variant of the magical interpolation feature*.

For example, it will raise an `InterpolationSyntaxError` in the event of a bad reference or a syntax error after a '%' character.

**Update 2**

That could be useful to precise that the `SafeConfigParser` class [has been renamed to ConfigParser in Python 3.2](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/cd90f6a3692e0f7ef0a13aae651e19a08d1f9b31/Lib/configparser.py#L1230). If you wonder which of the `SafeConfigParser` or the `ConfigParser` you should use in python 2.7, use the first (unless you have a very specific reason to use the second)

You could also make easier your future transition to python 3+, ([which should happen soon](https://pythonclock.org/)) by doing:

```
from ConfigParser import SafeConfigParser as ConfigParser
```

Comment: `ConfigParser` also has `interpolation` too. But thank you for the example that `SafeConfigParser` is stricter than `ConfigParser`.

Comment: I updated my answer with more details on the subject

Comment: Thank you. This is exactly the kind of information I was looking for. I realize that `SafeConfigParser` was the one to use. But I wanted to know what was wrong with the old one. I was wondering, for example, if the interpolation functionality of `ConfigParser` allowed arbitrary code execution from a config file. It sounds like it doesn't. And the reason the interface for the new one changed is that it will throw exceptions the old one didn't. So, the reason for the new name is not any immediately visible interface changes.

Answer (score 2):

`SafeConfigParser` is...

> Derived class of ConfigParser that implements a
>   more-sane variant of the magical interpolation feature. This
>   implementation is more predictable as well. New applications should
>   prefer this version if they don’t need to be compatible with older
>   versions of Python.

I think `SafeConfigParser` does not seem to consider Python version compatibility. `ConfigParser` also exists in Python 3 version, but `SafeConfigParser` does not exist. Exactly, `SafeConfigParser` is renamed `ConfigParser` and `ConfigParser` is removed in `3.2`. See this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2848711/why-is-there-raw-safeconfigparser-in-python-3).

So I think differences between `ConfigParser` and `SafeConfigParser` are usability and version compatibility.

**UPDATE:**

`SafeConfigParser` is just safer than `ConfigParser`. That's not to say that `ConfigParser` isn't safe. I tried to figure out what was safer. It supports more-sane variant of the [magical interpolation](https://github.com/spotify/luigi/issues/101) and it is more stricter than `ConfigParser`.

**So why SafeConfigParser is safe?**

The answer is `SafeConfigParser` is more strict. Example of strict is in @olinox14 answer.

The fact that `SafeConfigParser` has become the default `ConfigParser` in Python 3 doesn't necessarily mean you need to separate them.

**Ultimately,** `SafeConfigParser` is more strict. And it is recommended to use SafeConfigParser.

Comment: But, why is `SafeConfigParser` called **Safe** `ConfigParser`? What's safer about it? What was unsafe about the original `ConfigParser`?

Comment: Maybe it's not that B isn't safe. Just `SafeConfigParser` is more stricter than `ConfigParser` on `magical interpolation`. @Omnifarious

Comment: In what way is it a safer and more sane version? As far as I can tell from the docs there is no difference in the operation of the feature.

Comment: I updated my answer. This is my final conclusion. @Omnifarious

Answer (score 0):

According to https://docs.python.org/2/library/configparser.html:

On top of the core functionality, SafeConfigParser supports interpolation. This means values can contain format strings which refer to other values in the same section, or values in a special DEFAULT section. Additional defaults can be provided on initialization.

Comment: After reading the python libary source code, i've got that both of the ConfigParser and SafeConfigParser supports interpolation, and the main difference between them is the Safe one overrides the _interpolate()  and set() method. The ConfigParser mostly uses str % vars to implement _interpolate(), while the SafeConfigParser makes more check, and implements the  _interpolate() with another rule. As with the set() method

Comment: @Ticks what are the cons for using safeconfigparser? One I can think of is other languages might not support interpolation and one should want the config files to be language agnostic.

Comment: @himanshu219 - There is no reason not to use `SafeConfigParser`. You should always use `RawConfigParser` or `SafeConfigParser`. Plain old `ConfigParser` is there for backward compatibility. At least, that's the impression the documentation gives.